# cpanel always redirect my domain to sub folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, cpanel

I wrote a redirection rule using `cpanel`, my rule is if someone comes to `mydomain.com` it redirects to `mydomain.com/blog`

After a few days back I remove the above redirection rule, but still, when I try to visit `mydomain.com` it redirects to `mydomain.com/blog`

How could I troubleshoot this issue?

I removed all the folders in the file manager including `.htaccess` file and all the subdomain, domain redirection rules and databases, but still, it's redirecting.

Comment: clear your cookies and cache ... i always face this with Chrome

Comment: Thanks, @TemaniAfif, it works, I have spent more than 2 hours to figure this out